# Manually release lock made by sp_getapplock

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

So our application called `sp_getapplock` with an auto-generated resource key and we ran into a deadlock and application is stalled.
Is there any way to list all application locks (including resource key) made by `sp_getapplock` stored procedure or maybe there is another way of releasing these kind of locks rather then rebooting DB?

Comment: yep, set a timeout.... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-getapplock-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: @MitchWheat thanks, but any other ways? We will place a timeout, but it still will be around 6 hours or so.

Comment: When you run the proc, run another process right after to write that operation to a cache/persisted table with the return status code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-getapplock-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

> Locks placed on a resource are associated with either the current
>   transaction or the current session. Locks associated with the current
>   transaction are released when the transaction commits or rolls back.
>   Locks associated with the session are released when the session is
>   logged out. When the server shuts down for any reason, all locks are
>   released.

You could go around spid squashing until you kill the session and the lock gets released. 
You also mentioned deadlocking, so in that case you could fire up the profiler and run a deadlock graph, get the session that is killing off victims, and kill that spid. Once the session/transaction is gone, the lock should get released.

As for troubleshooting this in the future, log the information about the spid running the get app lock, log the return code/parameters from the proc execution, and then you can troubleshoot faster in the event of disaster.

Also, I highly recommend you put [sp_whoisactive](http://whoisactive.com/downloads/) on all instances. It will show who is blocking all your other processes unless they are being immediately killed off by a deadlockk.

Comment: We decided just to kill the hanged connections.

Answer (score 1):

> we ran into a deadlock

What kind of deadlock?  SQL Server should detect deadlocks involving application locks and regular locks and resolve them normally.

> Is there any way to list all application locks (including resource key) made by sp_getapplock

```
select request_session_id, resource_type, resource_description, request_mode, request_status, request_owner_type
from sys.dm_tran_locks
```

> [is there] another way of releasing these kind of locks rather then rebooting DB?

[Kill()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/kill-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) the session holding the lock.

Comment: Honest question, can you clarify what you are looking for with your question "What kind of deadlock?" I've never heard of different types of deadlocks and I assumed "We ran into a deadlock" was pretty straightforward as long as the person actually means deadlock and is not misusing the term.

Comment: A deadlock involving, say a Mutex in the application and an app lock in SQL Server wouldn't be detected, and would just freeze your app.  But SQL Server has deadlock detection, and will normally resolve a deadlock between two sessions by generating an error in one of the sessions.  So, why do you think you have a deadlock?  What is the symptom?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Answering your question - it's application deadlock based on this SQL Server stored procedure. We have a background task processor and seems that two tasks were scheduled and processed at the almost same time. Probably I should've been more clear in my question.